# Including MediaWiki Special:AllPages on another page

Tags: php, mediawiki

Is there a way to include the Special:AllPages on another MediaWiki page, i.e. I would like to list Special:AllPages at the bottom of the main page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the template in any page.  Note this excludes the search boxes.

```
{{Special:AllPages}}
```

There is more documentation about [namespaces on the MediaWiki site](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Namespaces).

Comment: Why does that not work for {{Special:UncategorizedPages}}?

Comment: @Wikis Not all pages in the [`Special` namespace](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Special_pages) may be [transcluded](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Transclusion).